# Why is the satellite dish still needed?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electronics, electrical-engineering, radio, antennas

How much does it amplify the signal? The receiver cannot pick up the signal without the dish?

Is it possible that it will disappear in 10 years? As the sensitivity of the receiver is enhanced?

For a radio, there is no need of a dish.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: For terrestrial radio there's probably a 100kW transmitter 20 miles away.  For satellite TV there's a 100W transmitter 22,000 miles away.  This is why you need a dish.

Comment: 1. antennas do not amplify anything, instead they collect. 2. terrestrial radio has a wavelength around 600m to 150m so a dish whose diameter must be at least a  wavelength is out of the question.

Comment: @hyportnex Actually VHF radio has wavelengths around 3m.  Dishes would still be impractically large.